# angular expression inside link_to in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

Does any one knows how insert the angular expression inside a link_to in rails.

```
<section ng-controller="listServiceCtrl">   
    <ul ng-repeat="service in servicelist">
        <li><%= link_to '{{ service.service}}', home_user_path('{{ service.id}}') %></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

I got an error for this.

Comment: You definitely can't do that, because anything in your erb tags is interpreted on the server side, before angular can touch it. You have to decide if you want to the do the loop in ruby or the links in regular html + angular.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you understand the boundary between server processing of the file, and client (browser) processing.

Rails processes the file and runs the server-side commands (like those in `<%= .. %>`). **It then outputs a file and serves it**. The browser receives this file. You can see what the browser receives by viewing the source of the page.

The browser runs the JavaScript of the page. This includes the Angular scripts. That JavaScript is what binds to expressions.

So you can't add Angular expressions to server-side code blocks, because the browser never sees the server-side blocks -- only what they output.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. Yes, I'm new in web development specially in angular and rails, your answer really helps me a lot. :)

Comment: Sorry, my answer seems to be irrelevant. The binding will still be output in the HTML and used as normal. Still, it doesn't help to mix server-side and client-side code when trying to understand a problem.

Answer (score 10):

If you look at the rails docs for `link_to()`, they say something like this:

```
link_to "Profile", profile_path(@profile)

# => <a href="/profiles/1">Profile</a>
```

So if you write:

```
<%= link_to '{{ service.service}}', ..... %>
```

...you will get the string:

```
"<a href=....>{{ service.service}}</a>"
```

...which is exactly what you are trying to get in the html for your angularjs.  So far, so good.

Next, the rails guide for *path helpers* shows this:

> In the case of **resources :photos** [in config/routes.rb]:
>
> **photos_path** returns /photos
>
> **new_photo_path** returns /photos/new
>
> **edit_photo_path(:id)** returns /photos/:id/edit (for instance,
>   **edit_photo_path(10)** returns /photos/10/edit)
>
> **photo_path(:id)** returns /photos/:id (for instance, photo_path(10)
>   returns /photos/10)

The following path helper in your code:

```
home_user_path(3)
```

...looks like it matches the format of the last path helper above.  Is your model named HomeUser?  If so, then the following:

```
home_user_path(3)
```

will return the string:

```
"/home_users/3"
```

Okay. But is it possible to write:

```
home_user_path('hello')
```

Does the argument have to be a number?  Will a string argument produce an error?  As it turns out, the line above returns the string:

```
"/home_users/hello"
```

So, it looks like you can use any arbitrary string as an argument for a rails path helper.  However, if you try the following in your view:

```
<% my_href = home_user_path('{{ service.id}}') 
   puts "*** #{my_href}"
%>
```

...then load the page, then look in the terminal window which displays the server output, then scroll up, you will see:

```
*** /home_users/%7B%7B%20service.id%7D%7D
```

What the heck is that? If you look closely, you can make out the text `service.id`, but what is that gibberish on either side?  If you have enough experience, you will recognize that as *url encoding*.  url's can only contain certain characters, and if you need to include an illegal character in a url, it has to be *url escaped*.  url escapes are recognizable by a leading `%` sign.  It's apparent that home_user_path() is url escaping the characters `{{` and `}}` in the url string before returning it.  If you check a list of legal url characters, braces are not included--as a result, braces must be escaped when appearing in a url.  So, rails path helpers automatically escape illegal characters in a url--that's normally a nice feature.

Of course, angularJS doesn't recognize that url escaped gibberish when it is used as the value for an href attribute in an `<a>` tag.  However, there is a way to reverse url escaping. Given the string:

```
"/home_users/%7B%7Bservices.id%7D%7D"
```

you can *unescape* the string to get the original string.  The ruby method that performs *url unescaping* is in the Ruby Standard Library:

```
ruby 1.9: CGI::unescape()

ruby 2.0: URI::unescape()
          URI::decode_www_form_component() <--Use this one!  Even though its name is confusing, it's more reliable.  See: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/207489

ruby 2.2: URI::decode_www_form_component()
```

(I'm actually going to use URI::unescape() in the following discussion to make things clearer--the new method's name is just too long and confusing.)

Apparently, rails does the require 'uri'(or require 'cgi') for you, so you can just call the method in your view.  And if you try:

```
<% url_escaped_href = home_user_path('{{ service.id}}') 
   my_href = URI::unescape(url_escaped_href)

   puts "*** #{my_href}"
%>
```

...you will see the following in the server window:

```
*** /home_users/{{ service.id}}
```

...which, of course, is what you want for the value of the href attribute in your `<a>` tag.  Therefore, you can write:

```
<%= link_to '{{ service.service}}', 
            URI::unescape( home_user_path('{{ service.id}}') ) 
%>
```

or equivalently:

```
<% url_escaped_href = home_user_path('{{ service.id}}') 
   my_href = URI::unescape(url_escaped_href)
%>

<%= link_to '{{ service.service}}', my_href %>
```

and that will produce the string:

```
<a href="/home_users/{{service.id}}">
   {{service.service}}
</a>
```

Then, when the html file is sent to your browser(note that a file is just one big string), your browser will recognize the `<a>` tag as html, and *render* it.  Then when the browser executes the javascript on the page, angularJS will perform its magic and replace the double curlies with the values of the javascript variables.

**One problem**: the link might get displayed before angularJS has a chance to replace the `double curlies` with a value.  If that happens, and the user clicks on the link, they will get a 404/Page Not Found error.  The advantage of using the `ng-href` attribute is that the link won't get displayed until after angularJS has a chance to replace the double curlies with values.  Therefore, you may want to forgo using the rails link_to() form helper and manually construct the link tag, similar to what Rimian posted:

```
  <% url_escaped_href = home_user_path('{{ service.id}}') 
     my_href = URI::unescape(url_escaped_href)
  %>

  <div>
  <a ng-href="<%= my_href %>">{{service.service}}</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, I tried your code and it works but when i click the link and go to the user/1/home path my angular script didn't load correctly, I will refresh it first so that all of my angular script works. how can I load my script when after I click the link? :)

Comment: @JuanDelaCruz, *All* your javascript code--including your angularJS code--should have loaded on the first page you visited.  Is it all in app/assets/javascripts?  If the page with the link is correct, check the link's href in the source html(View>Developer>View Source in Google Chrome), then clicking the link will load the next page, and the angularJS on that page should execute if it's written correctly.

Comment: Yes sir it was loaded everything in app/assets/javascripts and also viewed the view page source it was loaded there. When I clicked the linked, in my next page the angular expression will display {{ brgy.barangay }}
Name: {{ sp.firstname }} {{ sp.lastname }}

Age: {{ sp.birthdate }}

Street Address: {{ sp.brgy_address }} .. but when i refreshed it , everything will okay.

Comment: @Juan Dela Cruz, I can't duplicate your problem.  You'll have to post a whittled down example of your code--be very brief.  But first try this: Change the name of the second page to 'xshow.html.erb'.  Then create a new page named 'show.html' that has two lines in it:  `<div ng-app="appName" ng-controller="ShowCtrl">`  and `<div>{{sp.firstname}}</div></div>`.  Then create the ShowCtrl with one line inside the body of the controller:  `$scope.sp = {'firstname': 'Juan'};` (or the equivalent in coffeescript).  Then click on your link to take you to that page, and see what happens.

Comment: @Juan Del Cruz, By the way, to get a `user_home_path()` helper, I had to create two models: `User(has_many :homes)` and `Home(belongs_to :user)`, and then I had to create a nested resource in routes.rb.  Is that what you did?  And my user_home_path() helper requires 2 ids, e.g. `user_home_path(1, 2)` or `user_home_path({{service.id}}, 2)`

Comment: Sir, your answer really helps me a lot. I created a controller and factory that will get the current user details so that when I try to access in the other page no more rails `link_to` helper method. `<ul ng-repeat="service in servicelist">
        <li>
            <a href="/users/{{session_user.id}}/home">{{service.service}}   </a>
        </li> </ul>` but the problem with that when I clicked the link I should refresh the page first so that the script will be loaded and all the data will display.

Comment: seems like my code is to long for the stackoverflow. I can't post long post.

Comment: @JuanDelaCruz,  If you post your config/routes.rb and your two models Home? and User?, I can post a full example.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify your rails router so it knows what to do:

```
<a ng-href="<%= home_users_path %>?id={{service.id}}">{{service.service}}</a>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref